# Auto disconnect the load while charging the battery

Tags: battery-charging, switching, load

Here is a tentative schematic that would use the battery (3.7V, 3500mAh single 18650 battery) to power the load under normal circumstances. The charger is disconnected at this point. When the AC-DC adapter is connected to power the charger (5V at the charger input), the load will disconnect and the charger will start charging the battery. Would this work?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not work.  Current may flow through the body diode of Q1 from BATT+ to VBATT when you mean for it to be disconnected.

Try using back-to-back FETs in place of single FETs.